# JavaScript - Bootstrap option buttons validation in form

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, validation

I need help with the validation.
That's my code:

HTML:

```
<label for="option">כיתה נוכחית:</label>
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="radio" name="class" value="12" > י"ב
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="radio" name="class" value="11" > י"א
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="radio" name="class" value="10"> י'
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="radio" name="class" value="9"  id="9"  onkeyup="validateClass()"> ט'
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="radio" name="class" value="8" > ח'
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="radio" name="class" value="7" id="7" onkeyup="validateClass()"> ז'
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="radio" name="class" value="6" id="6" onkeyup="validateClass()"> ו'
  </label>
```

And the result:

[image: Results]

**Question**: I wanna check if the user clicked on one of the buttons.

I tried to do:

```js
if (calss10 === null)
```

I want to do this with: `onekeyup=" "`

Comment: It looks like you forgot to post your JavaScript code. Please make sure your question contains all of the code you've written.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will solve your problem.
You need to create a function that runs when the user submit the form (`onsubmit`)
this is a form example:
P.S you need to add an id to every radio button `id="class"`

```
 <form onsubmit="return Validate()">
    <label for="option">כיתה נוכחית:</label>
    <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
      <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="radio" name="class" value="12" > י"ב
      </label>
      <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="radio" name="class" value="11" > י"א
      </label>
      <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="radio" name="class" value="10"> י'
      </label>
      <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="radio" name="class" value="9"  id="9"  onkeyup="validateClass()"> ט'
      </label>
      <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="radio" name="class" value="8" > ח'
      </label>
      <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="radio" name="class" value="7" id="7" onkeyup="validateClass()"> ז'
      </label>
      <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="radio" name="class" value="6" id="6" onkeyup="validateClass()"> ו'
      </label>

</form>
```

```js
function Validate() {
    if (!Validate_Class())
        return false;
}
function Validate_Class() {
    if (!document.getElementById("class").checked) {
        alert("אתה חייב לבחור כיתה!");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't this get the job done?

```
var myClickedElement;

$('input[name="class"]').click(function(e) {
    myClickedElement = $(this);
});
```

Comment: Can you do it in JavaScript?

Comment: You have jQuery available. Why not use it?

Comment: Because I dont know JQuery

Comment: I'll leave it to others to write plain JS. I suggest you glance at a few of jQuery's api pages. It's very simple to learn if you understand JS, and has many advantages. Also, you should remove the Bootstrap tags if you don't want folks suggesting jQuery.